# Восстановление JPEG файлов в Ubuntu из NTFS

Tags: ubuntu, восстановление

При установке Ubuntu 16.04, совершил ошибку - удалил все существующие данные и установил Ubuntu на чистый диск.

До установки Ubuntu, у меня диск был разбит на 3: 1) Windows 2) Data 3) Ubuntu
После установки, остался 1 диск с полным объемом.

Поискав в гугле, нашел несколько утилит: PhotoRec и testdisk

Photorec:
Несмотря на то, что в описании PhotoRec сказано, что восстанавливает JPEG файлы, такой опции нет. (http://joxi.ru/VrwnW1atdx0WAX). Следуя гайду (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) Bruteforce Enabled не помогает.

TestDisk: quickscan не нашел документы из Windows, попробую запустить на ночь Deep Scan.

Интеерсуют меня впервую очередь JPEG файлы - это фотографии (бекап делаю, но фото из последнего отпуска не успел).

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: если тебе DeepSearch  не поможет - можешь попрощаться с данными. Очень сильно повезет, если они оказались в той части диска, в которую  Linux не записывался и в которую swap не попал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень рекомендую утилиту R-Studio. Она лучшая в своем роде.

Если повезет - она увидит остатки каталога файлов в таблице MFT или кусочки папок - тогда удастся выцепить целые файлы как они были в оригинале. Для этого рекомендуется запустить полное сканирование диска.

Если не повезет - у программы есть опция сигнатурного поиска. Она работает на основании предположения о том, что файлы были не фрагментированы. Т.е. она идет по секторам с 0 до MAX и найдя сигнатуру, соответствующую началу файла JPEG вырезает столько секторов в отдельный файл, сколько нужно. При этом естественно (!!!) имена файлов теряются.

Comment: R-Studio, действительно отличная утилита - нашла все потерянные фото. Вот только 79$ немаленькая сумма для разовой операции. Может есть бесплатные аналоги?